# Photoresist PCB - Traces always gets washed away with developer

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I have a positive acting presensitized UV-curable PCB board [(link)](https://core-electronics.com.au/pcb-kinsten-presensitized-positive-acting-photo-resist-114x165x1-6mm.html). I'm using the manufacturer-provided developer.

Supposedly, the parts that get exposed will get washed away by the developer. However, I observed that my traces are always the ones that get exposed no matter what arrangement I do. It seems like the "minority" always gets exposed.

What am I doing wrong? Is this the normal behavior for photoresist PCBs? I'm always using the same developer all cases.

[image]
Please ignore the scratches and blurry impressions. These are test runs. Left is first run, right is second run.

EDIT: added included pamphlet 
[image]

Comment: No, that doesn't make any sense. It seems like you have one negative and one positive board and managed to invert your printed layout exactly to the matching board to get the same result.

Comment: So far, I've tried it on 5 boards

Comment: @pandalion98 And you got the same result everytime regardless of which printed layout you used?

Comment: I'm afraid so, yes.

Comment: @pandalion98 that would mean if you only inverted half of it, it would still produce the same circuit, but I haven't heard of intelligent photo resist which does always that what the user doesn't want.

Comment: Many photoresists benefit from baking. I would hope that your board supplier would document any baking steps in their expose/develop/etch procedure.

Comment: @glen_geek Good point. I've added in the included pamphlet. They don't mention any baking steps.

Comment: @pandalion98 you do the "exposure box step"? I haven't seen that one in the boards I have used before. Though the result still doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Arsenal Basically "exposure" step. I think they sell a dedicated UV exposure box. But, on the package itself, they do mention other methods (Their exposure box: 90 seconds; Fluorescent lights: 6-10 minutes)

Comment: @Arsenal It seems like steps "A" and "B" are simply different ways of achieving the same step. See step "Etching": "Etching Tank" versus "Plastic Tray". With the exposure step, either it's "exposure box" or "fluorescent lamp".

Comment: @pandalion98 oh, so they mean you can do either A exposure box or B fluorescent light. I'm really bad at reading manuals these days...

Comment: Here is a link to the developer: http://www.kalexelectronics.com.au/kinsten-pcb-developer-dp-50/ .

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two curing mechanics known to me - first is UV light and second is **heat**. You may notice that traces on left PCB is much more accurate - that's an appropriate result for an UV curing. Right PCB, however, is ugly. It looks like heat traveled from traces outward and cured away photoresist. Also, film is really important - semi-transparent film is bad and soaked up paper is trash. You wont get any thin traces with that.

I would recommend moving exposure lamp away from PCB and increasing exposure time proportionally. That would help to reduce heat

UV curable photoresist really helps in creation of tiny traces and double-sided PCBs, however, with such huge trace width, tonetransfer technique would be superior